# What is the best free test tracking software?

Tags: testing

I'm not talking about bug tracking software (like Bugzilla or Jira). I'm looking for something that:

1. Stores test specifications in text format
2. Combines test specs into test coverage scenarios
3. Keeps track of the progress through testing scenarios
4. Links test specs with bug reports stored in Bugzilla
5. Generates progress reports
6. Is centrally managed on its own (i.e. is not a hack/extension on top of something else)

Comment: Take a look at this similar question - some of the suggestions may be helpful:
[simple-bug-tracking-suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626/simple-bug-tracking-suggestions)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

TestLink is a pretty nice open source test tracking tool with the features you need, and is still under active development.  Take a look at http://testlink.org/

Answer (score 10):

I haven't used this (yet), but [Testopia](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/testopia/) seems to meet all your requirements, especially the one about Bugzilla.

Answer (score 6):

I'm biased since I'm the primary author, but I think [Cuanto](http://trackyourtests.com) is pretty good. It allows you to track historical results for multiple test projects and you can store your analysis with the test results.

Answer (score 5):

[RTH](http://sourceforge.net/projects/rth/) is another open source test management tool

Answer (score 4):

I have personally used Trac (http://trac.edgewall.org/) which combines a simple issue tracker with Wiki functionality. Solved the need I had on my project.

Comment: I think the author was "not talking about bug tracking software".

Answer (score 4):

A while back I briefly looked at the free version of [QaTraq](http://www.softwaretesting.net/download/download.html). Although I left the team I was considering it for before we every got very far with the project, it was the frontrunner of the options I looked at at the time.

It's got quite a nice interface, and what seemed to me to be a very sensible test planning structure. I think one of the big downsides was the the open source version didn't have table support in the WYSIWYG test case editor - Not a showstopper, and could be fixed with a little development effort or by spending some money on the professional version.