# Is there any good open-source software to write test cases?

Tags: testing, case

I'd like to have historical memory of the test cases I usually do to verify a software suite, and the company in which I work now uses word or excel docs for this task, but I'd like something more focused on the type of task. What do you use? Is there any open-source software to fill with test cases?

Thanks

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62542/what-is-the-best-free-test-tracking-software

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try testopia for bugzilla
http://www.mozilla.org/projects/testopia/
it's pretty nice and free/open source.

Comment: In the whiletime I've used Testopia with great satisfaction, now there are many people working on it both from my company and customers; the only thing I'd prefer was different is that you can't have multi-product testplans but there are some kind of workarounds

Answer (score 4):

[TestLink](http://testlink.org) is another very nice option; I highly recommend it.